# HTML5 Ant Build Script

Tags: ant, html5boilerplate, build-script

I'm having trouble getting multiple pages working with the HTML Ant Build Script. This was working at one time where I would get multiple contatenated js files based on the different pages, but that has since stopped working. No errors. No warnings. Just stopped outputting properly.

I am using the HTML5 boilerplate for the HTML.

I'm using the latest version of the build script from: https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script

```
-index.html
    <!-- scripts concatenated and minified via build script -->
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script4.js"></script>
    <!-- end scripts -->

-index2.html has this:
    <!-- scripts concatenated and minified via build script -->
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script1.js"></script>
    <!-- end scripts -->
```

I have this set in the config file:

`file.pages = index.html, index2.html`

However, only index.html gets the single concatenated js file, while the index2.html gets the comments stripped and everything, it does not produce a separate concatenated js file. It just throws errors of missing js files because script1.js was used in the first and not copied over to the publish folder.

Make sense? Not sure what is wrong. It is probably something dumb I am doing, but I can't seem to find any answers by searching Stack Overflow for the last hour.